# how to get the last 2nd element of a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, slice

I am coming from a python background and do not understand this, is there a way in javascript to get the last 2nd element of a string?

eg `const name = "John"`

the closest i could find is `name.slice(-2)` but it return two characters, in other words, including the last character as well, which is not want i want.

Comment: name.charAt(name.length-2)?

Comment: sadly, javascript doesn't support negative indexing like python.

Comment: @georg thats my point. thanks

Answer (score 2):

JS's [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) isn't that similar to Python's slice syntax in spite of the name similarity. JS's `slice` with a single argument always goes from the provided number to the end of the string or array unless you specify a stop index as
well (inclusive, exclusive):

```js
const name = "John";

console.log(name.slice(-2, -1));
console.log(name[name.length-2]); // or use a normal index since you want 1 char
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings in JavaScript are arrays. For example, you can get the letter "h" in the word `"John"` by doing `name[2]`.

In this case, we can use the `.length` property of an array to get the amount of elements in that array, and then subtract 2 to get the second last element in it. Like so:

```js
let name = "John"
let secondLast = name[name.length - 2]

console.log(secondLast)
```

Subtracting 2, because the length of an array is a count, starts from 1, but array indexes are starting from 0. And we need the second last letter, not the last one.

Answer (score 0):

The slice() function takes two arguments, start and end. You can also index it like an array.

So you could write:

```js
const name = "John"
console.log(name.slice(-2,-1))

console.log(name[name.length-2])
```